# Проблемы с WebView

Tags: java, android

Организую экраны с помощью Flipper

```
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int layouts[] = new int[]{R.layout.scr1, R.layout.scr2, R.layout.scr3, R.layout.scr4};
    for (int layout : layouts) flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null));
```

В onCreate прописываю

```
 wv_scr4 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_scr4)
```

Пытаюсь загрузить страницу

```
   Log.d(Vrbl.LOG_TAG,"RisScr4");
   wv_scr4.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/faktor.html");
```

Но как только исполнение доходит до этой строки, программа вылетает.

Если перед этим разместить любые действия связанные с вызовом wv_scr4, программа сразу вылетает.

Например

```
 wv_scr4.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

или

```
 wv_scr4.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Все другие экраны содержат TextView и все хорошо, если убираю wv_scr4
В чем может быть проблема?

Логи с момента обращения к wv_scr4

```
     03-20 06:49:47.611 4313-4313/com.example.ka_ba.sotis D/MyLog: RisScr4
     03-20 06:49:47.611 4313-4313/com.example.ka_ba.sotis D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
     03-20 06:49:47.611 4313-4313/com.example.ka_ba.sotis W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6316288)
     03-20 06:49:47.611 4313-4313/com.example.ka_ba.sotis E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.ka_ba.sotis.MainActivity.RisScr4(MainActivity.java:455)                                                                           at com.example.ka_ba.sotis.MainActivity.onClOneTwoCard(MainActivity.java:300)                                                                           at com.example.ka_ba.sotis.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:132)                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-20 06:49:47.611 326-326/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.ka_ba.sotis/.MainActivity
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 387248 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 371056 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 354864 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 338672 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 322480 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 306288 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 290096 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 273904 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 257712 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 241520 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 225328 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 209136 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 192944 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 176752 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 160560 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 144368 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 128176 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 111984 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.635 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 95792 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.639 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 79600 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.639 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 63408 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.639 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 47216 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.639 343-345/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 31024 bytes, got 16192 
    03-20 06:49:47.651 326-329/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 581K, 13% free 11187K/12807K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 13ms
    03-20 06:49:47.651 326-340/system_process D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
    03-20 06:49:48.139 326-394/system_process I/qtaguid: Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10021) res=-1 errno=1
    03-20 06:49:48.139 326-394/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: setKernelCountSet(10021, 1) failed with errno -1
    03-20 06:49:48.139 326-339/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{536a8728 com.example.ka_ba.sotis/.MainActivity}
    03-20 06:49:48.171 504-504/com.android.launcher W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    03-20 06:49:48.175 504-504/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8537c00): name, size, mSize = 1469, 1200, 692688
```

Comment: Логи в студию..

Comment: Когда wv_scr4 биндите id верный указываете?

Comment: <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv_scr4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </WebView>

Comment: Когда биндите wv_src4 на ViewFlipper какой элемент отображается? Может он просто не находит webview.

Comment: Заремарил wv_scr4.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/faktor.html"); и добавил TextView c текстом добавленным в xml. Все работает и отображается, прокрутка между экранами работает. Но как только пытаюсь обратится программно tv_scr4.setText("123456"); прога вылетает.

Comment: Ошибка была обнаружена. Заключалась в следующем: связка wv_scr4 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_scr4) была сделана до объявления связки flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper); и его связи с экранами. Стоило перенести связку WebView после и все заработало.